# Display of data in access report based on form selection

Tags: ms-access-2007

I have a check box on my access form. If the user selects that check box , one column in an access report should display the values in 1000's

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

By passing the value of the checkbox into the OpenArgs when you run the report, you can set the format of the column. Here's what the report opening code might look like:

```
Private Sub cmdRun_Click()

    Dim bFormatted As Boolean
    bFormatted = chkFormat.Value
    DoCmd.OpenReport "ReportName", acViewPreview, , , , bFormatted

End Sub
```

Then in the Open event of the Report:

```
Private Sub Report_Open(Cancel As Integer)

    Dim sArgs As String
    Dim bFormatted As Boolean

    sArgs = OpenArgs & ""
    If sArgs <> "" Then
        bFormatted = CBool(sArgs)
    End If

    If bFormatted Then
        txtBox.Format = "0000"
    End If

End Sub
```

I have not checked the correct format. That's left up to you.

Comment: Did you ever try this?